# Represent node relationship using Python NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I have around 200K nodes and their relationship in a XML file as follows:

node_A -    node_B  direct, node_A -    node_G  inverse, node_A -   node_H  direct,  node_A -   node_X  inverse, node_A -   node_Y  direct

I need to model the nodes and their relationship in the XML file using Python NetworkX graph data structure and based on user input (e.g node_A   up) find the relationship among nodes and output the nodes as follows:

output: node_B -    up, 
    node_G -    down, 
    node_H -    up, 
    node_X -    down, 
    node_Y -    up

Here meaning is that based on node relationship the app should sort/filter the nodes. For example if relationship of node_A to node_B is direct and node_A to node_X is inverse output will be node_B - up and node_X - down as in the output example above.

Please help me to suggest which NetworkX graph data structure I should be using. An example would be a great help.

Thanks in advance
Prakash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a parser for doing this. Take a look at [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples).

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion. I went through pyparsing module but it's just a parser not a graph data structure which I am looking for to represent nodes and find relationship among nodes as described in the question.

Comment: You are missing the point. Since you have your data in xml and only you know the xml structure. You could `pyparse` it into your own user-defined object and then add 'em up into networkx using `G.add_node()` and the `G.add_edge` methods